# How to format the response from OWIN middleware

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, owin

Currently, this is the format of Owin response :

```
{
    access_token: "qefelgrebjhzefilrgo4583535",
    token_type: "bearer",
    expires_in: 59
}
```

But all the other response from my web api is in this format :

```
{
    status: 200,
    data: {id = 1, name = 'test'}
}
```

As we can see data is a member of the response JSON and accessible by using `response.data`.

So the question now is how can I format my owin authenticator response to look like this.

```
{
    data : {
         access_token: "qefelgrebjhzefilrgo4583535",
         token_type: "bearer",
         expires_in: 59    
    }

}
```

From this, in my interceptor i can just return `response.data` regardless if it is a normal request or a token-authentication request.

Currently i have this implementation to check if the response is from token or from a normal request and I didn't like it.

```
RestangularConfigurer.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
           if (url.indexOf('token'))
               return response;
           else 
                return response.data;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can. The OAuth response is built internally and you should stick with that format.

There is also another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656969/how-to-modify-token-endpoint-response-body-with-owin-oauth2-in-asp-net-web-api-2) about this, which is quite a similar problem. You can always build a new OAuth provider from sratch, but I think it's a bit overkill.

Anyway, if the problem is in the JS part and you don't like to check for "token" string, you can try this way:

```
RestangularConfigurer.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
       if (response.data !== undefined)
           return response.data;
       else return response;
    });
```

Comment: the if condition is the same intent with the above and about the link i already used token endpoint to add additional params.\