# How to extend IdentityServer4 workflow to run custom code

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4

I have a basic Identityserver4 implementation based on the [quick start sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src/QuickstartIdentityServer).

In my startup I have the following:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        app.UseIdentityServer();
    }
```

I want to extend the IdentityServer4 workflow so that after the access token is generated I can run business logic (based on the claims in the access token) and modify the response send to the calling client. I tried creating a .NET core middleware but it seems the IdentityServer middleware short-circuits the rest of the pipeline (no middleware place after the UseIdentityServer will be executed).

Are they any extension method in Identityserver4 that I can use to always modify the response issued by IdentityServer4? I am using the credentials grant. Essentially I want to run some business logic to modify the response send to the client once IdentityServer4 is done with its workflow

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that.
When you request any IdentityServer endpoint, IdentityServer middleware short-circuits the rest of the pipeline.
You can check source code:
[IdentityServerMiddleware class](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Hosting/IdentityServerMiddleware.cs#L62).

I believe it was done for a reason. But if you really need to modify the response, you have at least three options:

1. Create a fork and remove **`return`** operator from
   **`IdentityServerMiddleware`** **`Invoke`** method (be careful to short-circuit the rest of the pipeline adding **`return`** into your last middleware).
2. Create your own **`IdentityServerMiddleware`**, **`IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions`** implementations and use
   them instead of default.
3. Place your middleware before the UseIdentityServer. Your middleware should look like this:

   ```
   public ResponseBodyEditorMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
   {
       _next = next;
   }

   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
   {
       // get the original body
       var body = context.Response.Body;

       // replace the original body with a memory stream
       var buffer = new MemoryStream();
       context.Response.Body = buffer;

       // invoke the next middleware from the pipeline
       await _next.Invoke(context);

       // get the body as a string
       var bodyString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.GetBuffer());

       // make some changes
       bodyString = $"The body has been replaced!{Environment.NewLine}Original body:{Environment.NewLine}{bodyString}";

       // update the memory stream
       var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyString);
       buffer.SetLength(0);
       buffer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

       // replace the memory stream with updated body
       buffer.Position = 0;
       await buffer.CopyToAsync(body);
       context.Response.Body = body;
   }
   ```