# Return custom error message for grant_type field missing ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

I need to build an API which returns custom error message on an OAuth request which doesn't have a grant_type field or scope field. There are other requirements where I need to return custom error message where the grant_type is passed but is incorrect. I was able to do it using the below code

```
public override async Task ValidateTokenRequest(OAuthValidateTokenRequestContext context)
{      
            if (!context.TokenRequest.IsClientCredentialsGrantType)
            {
                context.SetTokenRequestError("invalid_grant", "Invalid grant type", "invalid_grant", "Grant type is invalid");
                return;
            }
            await Task.Run(() => context.Validated());
 }

public static void SetTokenRequestError(this OAuthValidateTokenRequestContext context, string code, string cmessage, string field, string fmessage)
        {
            var response = new
            {
                code = $"{code}",
                message = $"{cmessage}",
                errors = new[] {
                    new { field = $"{field}", message = $"{fmessage}"}
                }
            };

           
            var json = response.ToJsonString();
            context.SetError(json);
            context.Response.Write(json);
            InvokeTokenRequest(context);
        }

static async Task InvokeTokenRequest(OAuthValidateTokenRequestContext context)
{
            var owinResponseStream = new MemoryStream();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";            
            context.Response.Body = owinResponseStream;
}
```

A POST request to the below token endpoint without the grant_type field in the body of the request  should return the below. For my life, I can't find out which OAuth middleware function, I need to override to achieve this

[image]

```
{
  "code": "schema_validation_failed ",
  "message": "Validation failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "grant_type",
      "message": "field is missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

I looked at the below but was unable to follow it. Any hints would be appreciated !!
[How to modify token endpoint response body with Owin OAuth2 in Asp.Net Web API 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656969/how-to-modify-token-endpoint-response-body-with-owin-oauth2-in-asp-net-web-api-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else, if they had to customize OAuth error responses in ASP.NET Web API, especially for the grant_type field being empty, please use the below code in your ValidateClientAuthentication method where ideally you collect the client ID and secret values

```
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
                string clientId;
                string clientSecret;
                if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
                {
                    context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
                }
                
                // Verifying if grant_type key exists in the token payload
                if (context.Parameters.Get("grant_type") == null)
                {
                    context.SetClientAuthError("schema_validation_failed", "Validation failed", "grant_type", "field is missing");
                    return;
                }
     }
```